# Outlook 2007 and outlook 2010 connection status connected but last updated was hours ago or sometimes days

Tags: microsoft-outlook-2010, microsoft-outlook-2007, office365, exchange-2013

We are having issues in **Outlook 2007** and **Outlook 2010**, Outlook status were connected but last updated was hours ago or sometimes days.

Below were methods we used as our temporary solution but we haven't resolve it yet for permanent solution as this was happening to our outlook client repeatedly.

- Recreate outlook profile. "This method was our last resort for 
        this issue and the worst one. It would take minutes or hours 
        depending on its mailbox size to  be downloaded together with the 
        outlook configuration.
- Cached and un-cached mode outlook profile. "In this process only outlook 2013 will get fixed and updated but in outlook 2007 and 2010 were not."
- Deleting .OST "After deleting the outlook .ost file all mails will be downloaded again the same as you recreated your outlook profile."
- Repairing outlook profile "It would work and get fixed but not to all outlook users."

Hope you can help us with this.

Thanks,

Comment: +1 have seen this mostly in cases when the mailbox size is over 5GB